# Jinja2-Flask bootstrap modal inside a for loop doesn't work

Tags: python, flask, jinja2, bootstrap5-modal

I am trying to list a bunch of information on a table and I want user to be able to click an icon and see the description of the content. My project is TODO list. I am showing the user {{ task.title }} within a for loop and I have an icon/button next to it to open the modal.

When I put my modal button inside my for loop and modal content outside the for loop, I am not able to catch the current data, example:
{{ task.description }} I can't catch this information from my database because I am outside the loop and I get jinja2 error because of this saying task is undefined.

If I put my modal content inside the for loop, then my modal is not working properly, modal screen kinda gets foggy and faded. I am adding an image of this error here.
[IMG when I put my modal content inside the for loop, I get this screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vVA0z.png)

Anyone solved this issue before? It probably has an easy solution but I've been trying for days now I am kinda tilted...
My code:

```
<tbody class="align-middle">
 {% for task in active_tasks: %}
 <tr>
   <td>{{task.deadline}}</td>

   <td>
   <a type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-bs-toggle="modal" data-bs-target="#modal">
     Title
   </a>
   <div class="modal fade" id="modal" tabindex="-1" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
     <div class="modal-dialog modal-dialog-centered modal-dialog-scrollable">
       <div class="modal-content">
         <div class="modal-header">
           <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel">Modal title</h5>
           <button type="button" class="btn-close" data-bs-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"></button>
         </div>
         <div class="modal-body">
             {{ task.description }}
         </div>
         <div class="modal-footer">
           <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-bs-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
           <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
         </div>
       </div>
     </div>
   </div>
   </td>

   <td>
       {% if task.priority == "High Priority": %}
     <span class="badge bg-danger">{{ task.priority }}</span>
       {% elif task.priority == "Medium Priority": %}
     <span class="badge bg-warning">{{ task.priority }}</span>
       {% else: %}
     <span class="badge bg-success">{{ task.priority }}</span>
       {% endif %}
   </td>

   <td>
     <a href="{{ url_for('complete_task', id=task.id) }}" data-mdb-toggle="tooltip" title="Complete">
       <i class="bi bi-check-lg check-icon"></i></a>

     <a href="{{ url_for('delete_task', id=task.id, status='active') }}" data-mdb-toggle="tooltip" title="Remove">
       <i class="bi bi-trash trash-icon"></i></a>
   </td>
 </tr>
 {% endfor %}

</tbody>
```

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

Don't add your modal into your for loop. You can access the data using vanilla javascript. Search this in Google or YouTube

```js
access table data with button using vanilla javascript
```